# How to use both onSuccess() and onBitmapLoaded() with Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I'm fecthing an image to be displayed in a StaggeredLayout. So, i'm using the onBitmapLoaded() method from Target to keep the aspect ratio.

```
picasso.load(mCursor.getString(ArticleLoader.Query.THUMB_URL))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.photo_background_protection)
                .into(new Target() {


            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                float width = bitmap.getWidth();
                float height = bitmap.getHeight();

                float aspectRatio = width / height;

                holder.thumbnailView.setAspectRatio(aspectRatio);
                holder.thumbnailView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                holder.imageProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

        });
```

I want to call the onSuccess method to check if the image was laoded successfully, so I can make the progessBar invisible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use another ".into()" to firstly check if the image was loaded.

2nd answer to this might be useful to you : [Android picasso check if image url exist before load into imageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165571/android-picasso-check-if-image-url-exist-before-load-into-imageview)

Comment: It doesn't helps. I cannot call .into() twice, so I can't call onBitmapLoaded() AND onSuccess().

Comment: @IgorGreccoLacourt I have no issue to call `Picasso.get()... .into()` twice **nested** of callback, and is not mean to direct access `.into()` without `Picasso.get()` prefix.